# How to construct a list of files from the `start group ... end group` linker option

Tags: c++, g++

I've built V8 static library as explained [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Embedding#run-the-example). Now I'm trying to use it to create a sample HelloWorld application. The problem is that the docs don't say which files from the build I'll need to reference in my sample project. They only show how the project can be compiled using `g++`:

```
g++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello-world -Wl,--start-group \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/{libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform,libsampler},\
third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n},src/inspector/libinspector}.a \
-Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
```

I've read a bit about `g++` options and assume that the files list constructed from `--start-group...--end-group` linker option is what I need to reference in my project when compiling. But I don't understand how to construct that list of files. I thought that there will be files like

```
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_base
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libbase
...
```

But they are not there. Instead, there are folders:

```
out.gn/x64.release/obj/v8_base
out.gn/x64.release/obj/v8_libbase
out.gn/x64.release/obj/v8_external_snapshot

...
```

with `.obj` files. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commandline fragment:

```
 -Wl,--start-group \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/{libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform,libsampler},\
third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n},src/inspector/libinspector}.a \
-Wl,--end-group
```

will be expanded by the shell before `g++` sees it and will become:

```
 -Wl,--start-group \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_base.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libbase.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_external_snapshot.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libsampler.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/third_party/icu/libicui18n.a \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/src/inspector/libinspector.a \
-Wl,--end-group
```

This will tell `g++` to request the linker, `ld`, to link
all of the static libraries:

```
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_base.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libbase.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_external_snapshot.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libsampler.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/third_party/icu/libicui18n.a
out.gn/x64.release/obj/src/inspector/libinspector.a
```

and also, because of `--start-group ... --end-group` to examine
this set of libraries recursively in symbol resolution until
it yields no new undefined references (rather than just once each
in order, as per default)

If your build tree does not contain that set of static libraries then
it may be that the git branch you are building with is not in agreement
with the documentation you are following. In that case, you can look
for the static libraries in question - the eight `*.a` files - elsewhere 
in your tree and replace:

```
out.gn/x64.release/obj/{libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform,libsampler},\
third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n},src/inspector/libinspector}.a \
```

with a list of explicit absolute or relative filenames of the libraries you find. Then
try your luck with a build.

If you can't find any candidates then the documentation you are following
is hopelessly out of whack with the build tree you are working with.